# Best data structure for this sort of word lookup / spellcheck?

Tags: algorithm, spell-checking, trie, spelling

I have a list of words such as:

```
mmad
mmaaddd
bbad
bbaadddd
```

Let's suppose that mad and bad are considered to be valid words according to some dictionary. Is there any ideal algorithm or data-structure to find matches for these misspellings? I was thinking that a trie would be useful, but I wasn't sure how that would come into play if the valid word list / dictionary consists of thousands of words.

EDIT: I should mention that I'm not concerned about the words being dispelled from a character point of view, ie I don't want "mmad" getting corrected to "sad" or something similar. I think that's what Levenshtein distance and LD distance would be better for; this problem is a weird subset of that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: A [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) is usually pretty good for that, you might use [Ukkonen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm) to construct one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in your edit. You define the logic for how it is used in the end. If `sad` is in your dictionary, then `bad` and `sad` and `mad` are viable alternatives. You'd use LD to find out the closest match to words you have, then use some other logic to pick the right one.

Comment: It seems that, when you say "these misspellings", you mean "a restricted subclass of misspellings" (since you say you don't want "mmad" corrected to "sad"), but you don't ever say exactly what that subclass is.  In your examples, all the misspellings are generated from valid words by repeating some character(s) -- is that the subclass you want to correct?